# Automatically imports new/incoming .csv files from a folder through a server into SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server, csv

I am required to create a console application using C# that does the said function. We have a server that has a folder where the `.csv` files are located. The console app must be able to parse the contents of the new `.csv` files and then store the data contained in them to the SQL Server database.

My code so far:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string csvPath = @"C:\\users\blahblah\file.csv";

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[3] {
            new DataColumn("Id", typeof(int)),
            new DataColumn("First_Name", typeof(string)),
            new DataColumn("Last_Name",typeof(string)) });

    string csvData = File.ReadAllText(csvPath);

    foreach (string row in csvData.Split('\n'))
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row))
        {
            dt.Rows.Add();
            int i = 0;

            foreach (string cell in row.Split(','))
            {
                dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1][i] = cell;
                i++;
            }
        }
    }

    string consString = @"Data Source=blah blah";

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(consString))
    {
        using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(con))
        {
            //Set the database table name
            sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.Sample";
            con.Open();

            sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Note:

- Our server has an IP address which I could connect into then specify the folder location of the files.
- My code above only collects one specific `.csv` file.
- The console app should be running always.

I am not good with explaining so I hope you get my point. I will appreciate any help.

Comment: this sounds to me more like a job for a service than a console application

Comment: @fubo The thing is some of these .csv files have different formats so I also have to take care of that as it all will be stored in one table only on the sql server database.

Comment: Have you considered using [Integration Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx) instead? I'd expect you'd get everything you need out of the box, make your live easier and learn a new technology as you go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The console app should be running always.

Then, you better implement this task as a Service (Windows Service, WCF Service etc.).

> My code above only collects one specific .csv file.

Use [`FileSystemWatcher`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.100).aspx) to receive an event whenever your file is present, updated etc.

Comment: I was writing exactly the same answer... and you beat me.

Comment: Thanks. I'll check this out.